# Git combining features

Tags: git

let's say I start a new branch feature1.

I commit feature 1, merge with master.

Then I start a new branch feature 2. I commit feature 2, merge w master.

Later on I decide I don't want feature 1, I want to remove it. Is there any way to remove feature 1 while keeping feature 2?

Answer (score 2):

you can revert commit of merge by commit hash
`$ git revert -m 1 [sha_of_C9]`

more details are [here](https://git-scm.com/blog/2010/03/02/undoing-merges.html)

Comment: But `git revert` would only undo one commit thus merge with feature 2 would be removed. But so far I get from his question. He wants to skip merge with feature 2 and undo only merge with feature 1. But this is not possible, you have to revert two times then again merge with feature 2 branch.

Comment: What if not different branches? What if you want to revert commit 2 but keep commit 3 in same branch?

Comment: in that case `git rebase -i <sha before branch diverged>` is the only option I guess.